# Angular 7 Jasmine unit test: how to get component NativeElement?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my main component html there is a `my-grid` component

main.component.html

```
 <my-grid
    id="myDataGrid"
    [config]="gridOptions"
 </my-grid>
```

In main.component.specs.ts How can can I get `my-grid` NativeElement?

I have 1 test so far which checks that grid is being rendered

```
it('should render grid', () => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
     const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
     expect(compiled.querySelector('my-grid')).not.toBe(null);
})
```

Comment: I think `compiled.querySelector('my-grid')` is a native Element? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `debugElement` to query your component:

**Example**

```
const debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyGridComponent));
const nativeElement = debugElement.nativeElement;
const component: MyGridComponent = debugElement.componentInstance;
```

Comment: I get `null` if I query the component itself.